# Как запускать jSSLKeyLog for Wireshark?

Tags: java, wireshark

Пожалуйста, поясните инструкцию: http://jsslkeylog.sourceforge.net/

- Во-первых скачать jSSLKeyLog и извлечь его. **Куда?**
- Найдите командную строку, используемую для запуска программы `Java` (как правило, скрыты в некоторые `script` или `bat` файл) вы хотите контролировать, это будет выглядеть, как правило,  **Это обычная командная строка?**

  **Как правильно сделать это, без точек?**

  ```
  java ... -jar file.jar ...
  ```

  или

  ```
  Java ... some.class.Name ...
  ```
- Теперь добавьте дополнительный параметр непосредственно после имени команды Java, который

  ```
  -javaagent: jSSLKeyLog.jar = / путь / к / your_logfile.log
  ```

  так что полная команда выглядит следующим образом:

  ```
  java -javaagent: jSSLKeyLog.jar = / путь / к / your_logfile.log ... -jar file.jar
  ```
- Вы можете дать абсолютный или относительный путь к `jSSLKeyLog.jar` и к вашему
    журнальному файлу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53666/discussion-on-question-by-artgrek13-jsslkeylog-for-wireshark--).

Comment: Автор, когда вы формулируете вопрос с глаголом в повелительном наклонении («пояснить инструкцию»), он звучит, как приказ. Не стоит так делать, это невежливо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Распаковываем скачанный zip архив, куда вам удобно, я распаковал в диск `C:\`, и переименуем извлечённую папку что бы не путаться из **jSSLKeyLog** в **SSLFolder**

2) Нажимаем Start + R, пишем CMD, нажимаем OK

3) Входим в каталог SSLFolder: `C:\Users\ArtGrek>cd c:\SSLFolder\` *жмем enter*

4) Пишем: `c:\SSLFolder>java -javaagent:jsslkeylog.jar=sslkeylog.log -jar jsslkeylog.jar`

Лишние пробелы не ставить

У меня выдало вот такое сообщение, как я понял, это нормально

> Logging all SSL session keys to: sslkeylog.log
>
> no main manifest attribute, in jsslkeylog.jar